# 500 Internal Server Error apache ubuntu python

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache, flask, http-status-code-500

Содержимое папки с веб-сервисом выглядит так:

```
var
   www
      pythonProject
          pythonProject
              __pycache__
              static
              templates
              venv
              main.py
              index.py
          index.wsgi
```

Содержимое файла insex.wsgi:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке /etc/apache2/wites-available/ есть файл FlaskApp.conf, его содержимое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из файла index.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

from main import pipe

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/neuron_net', methods=['POST'])
def get_class():
    if not request.json or not 'text' in request.json:
        return jsonify({'error': 'empty text'})
    info = pipe(request.json['text'])
    if info[0] == 'empty':
        return jsonify({'error': 'empty text'})
    if info[0] != 'empty':
        message = {'text': request.json['text'],
                    'id_class': str(info[0]),
                   'class': info[1],
                   'probability': info[2]}
        return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Делал все так, как показано на этом сайте:
https://www.8host.com/blog/razvyortyvanie-prilozheniya-flask-na-servere-ubuntu/

Я посылаю post запросы на этот сервер и у меня вылазит такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а что в `error.log`, в котором и надо искать дополнительную информацию, как вам прямо пишут?

Comment: пишет, что нет такого модуля flask, хотя я уже установил его и через pip и через pip3, используя sudo. Может ubuntu использует Python 2 вместо Python 3?

Comment: Вполне может быть. На одном сервере могут быть не только разные питоны, но и разные виртуальные окружения одной версии питона с разным набором библиотек. Надо как-то настраивать через переменные окружения, какой питон должен использоваться. Я в этом не силён. Вы могли установить `Flask` в одно окружение, а веб-сервер использует другое. Надо как-то их поженить.

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но рекомендую отказаться от использования Apache и перейти на более современный стек, например nginx + gunicorn

Comment: @andreymal есть гайд, как это сделать?